# Java daemon Handler auto terminates

Tags: java, multithreading, daemon

I'm creating a class for watching (for changes) a given list of directives through implementation of a class that implements WatchService.

and started through Main like so:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ClassHandler CH= new ClassHandler();
}
```

My problem is, when started, it auto terminates. Probably because the Java GC can find no references to it? Haven't had this problem before, what can I do to keep it active?

Edit: Thank you for your reply. When I try this, it still terminates immediately.

```
Thank you for your reply. Something like this?

'public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){  
        public void run(){  
            try {
                new ClassHandler();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };  
    Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);  
    thread.setDaemon(true); //t.setDaemon(true);  
    thread.start();  
}'
```

That still terminates immediately however.

Edit edit:

Nevermind, found the mistake. I forgot to "activate" the watchservice, giving nothing nothing to do! It works now. Thanks for the help however!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are creating a Thread object somewhere in your code. You should use the setDaemon method, if so.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDaemon(boolean)